# compile a stream of data in C?

Tags: c, stream, compilation

Is it possible to compile a stream of data rather than compiling a `.c` file using gcc? for example, is it possible that instead of having my code stored in any `xyz.c` file, I can directly compile the code?

Comment: the gcc will not know how to create an object file from the stream nor will it know how to reference functions in your source code if no files were provided. why not simply stream your data into a file? another possibility would be to use an interpreter like CINT for example.

Comment: Understood. Don't want to make things so complicated. Thanks though :)

Comment: This also works for clang, if anyone was interested!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use gcc options [`-x`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x-75) and `-`

```
$ echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nmain(){puts("Hello world");return 0;}' | gcc -xc -ogarbage - && ./garbage && rm garbage
Hello world
```

---

The single line command above is made up of the following parts:

```
echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nmain(){puts("Hello world");return 0;}' # "source"
|                                                                   # pipe
gcc -xc -ogarbage -                                                 # compile
&&                                                                  # and
./garbage                                                           # run
&&                                                                  # and
rm garbage                                                          # delete
```

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Shell_one-liner#C) may answer you question, though it is rarely useful.

Comment: sorry if I don't write simply thank you, but it is too short, so just imagine I thank you (everytime), for the other counter-downvoting too :)

Comment: No worries @Shin; you don't need to thank me (though it's appreciated). Next time your answer is just a link, copy some of the information from the link to SO itself: this way, readers do not need to click the link to see the main part of the answer. If they want to dig deeper, they can click the link and read the rest.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; I was just concerned about licensing, read now that this is cc-wiki with attribution, I suppose it's compatible with what rc license is.

Comment: as long as you don't overdo the copy/paste and clearly indicate the source, I think it falls under the "fair use" rule. I just now [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615204/mysql-c-api-handle-text-field/6615721#6615721) a question with basically a link to the source :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file, stream the code into it, then create another process(that is, the compiler) giving it the file as an argument. Then create another process(that is, the linker) and it will create an exe for you. And finally you can launch that exe as a new process. ***But why?!:)***

Comment: I'm working on a project- online c compiler. I was just wondering that instead of actually saving the file and then compiling it,if it was possible to compile and run it without saving it in a file. :)

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara: No, I don't think you can.

Comment: @Armen: you can ... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612169/compile-a-stream-of-data-in-c/6612503#6612503) (of course the resulting binary is still saved as a file)