# MySQL C API Handle TEXT field

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

When one uses Prepared Statements in MySQL C API to handle TEXT field result, one has to specify the length of the string for an out binding:

```
 MYSQL_BIND    out_bind;
 char          str_data[STRING_SIZE]; 
 my_bool       is_null;
 my_bool       error;

 ....
 /* STRING COLUMN */
 out_bind.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
 out_bind.buffer = str_data;
 out_bind.buffer_length = STRING_SIZE;
 out_bind.is_null= &is_null;
 out_bind.length= &length;
 out_bind.error= &error;

 mysql_stmt_bind_result(statement, out_bind)
```

In the given example STRING_SIZE is the known constant, but how to be with TEXT fields where data length can vary from small sizes to megabytes?

Is there standard approaches for this?

Comment: Ugh! `str_data` by itself (after decaying) is a `char *`. Why are you converting to `char *`? :)

Comment: You are right. It is just a rudiment that stayed here after moving from a real code to this simplified example. Never mind.

Comment: I dont remember exactly, but you get this in return structures

Comment: Like out_bind.length in this example? ;) But you have to do the binding prior calling the statement that means that you have to allocate memory prior too. And you have to know the amount of memory to allocate. We have kind of complicated querry and do it twice would be kind of ugly solution... I believe...

Comment: How about using mysql builtin functions to return size of a field with OCTET_LENGTH() in the same query, so you can first allocate enough data and then actually read it in one pass


---
select count(*) as 'documents', sum(octet_length(document_data)) as total_size, avg(octet_length(document_data)) as avg_size from DOCUMENTS;

Comment: No way as I understand it. In prepared statements one binds ones fields then one calls statement and the addresses given in the bindings are filled by data. So the length is filled at the same time char* buffer is filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual page for `mysql_stmt_fetch`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html) says:

> In some cases you might want to determine the length of a column value before fetching it with mysql_stmt_fetch(). ... To accomplish this, you can use these strategies:
>
> - Before invoking `mysql_stmt_fetch()` to retrieve individual rows, pass `STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH` to `mysql_stmt_attr_set()`, then invoke `mysql_stmt_store_result()` to buffer the entire result on the client side. Setting the `STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH` attribute causes the maximal length of column values to be indicated by the `max_length` member of the result set metadata returned by `mysql_stmt_result_metadata()`.
> - Invoke `mysql_stmt_fetch()` with a zero-length buffer for the column in question and a pointer in which the real length can be stored. Then use the real length with `mysql_stmt_fetch_column()`.

You might also like to read the [manual page for `mysql_stmt_bind_result`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-bind-result.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I have solved this problem like pmg saids in first point, using STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH setting, here is my code :

```
MYSQL_STMT    *stmt;
MYSQL_BIND    bind[1];
MYSQL_BIND    bind_result[1];

// _con your mysql connection 
stmt = mysql_stmt_init(_con);
if (!stmt)
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_init(), out of memory\n");
  exit(0);
}

char* aQuery = (char*) "'your query'";
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, aQuery, strlen(aQuery)))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_prepare(), INSERT failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

    // Here fill binded parameters (here a string)
memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));

const char* aStr = ioType.c_str();
long unsigned int aSize = ioType.size();

bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer= (char *) aStr;
bind[0].buffer_length= 2048;
bind[0].is_null= 0;
bind[0].length= &aSize;

/* Bind the buffers */
if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_bind_param() failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

    // Reauest meta data information
MYSQL_RES* aRes = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(stmt);

    // Set STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH attribute
my_bool aBool = 1;
mysql_stmt_attr_set(stmt, STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH, &aBool);

/* Execute the select statement - 1*/
if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute(), 1 failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

if (mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt)) {
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute(), 1 failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}       

// Retrieving meta data information
MYSQL_FIELD* aField = &aRes->fields[0];

fprintf(stdout, " field %s \n",aField->name);
fprintf(stdout, " field length %d \n",(int) aField->length);
fprintf(stdout, " field max length %d \n", (int) aField->max_length);


int totalrows = mysql_stmt_num_rows(stmt);
fprintf(stdout, " fetched %d description\n",totalrows);
fprintf(stdout, " field count %d \n",(int) aRes->field_count);

long unsigned int aMaxSize;
char* aBuffer = (char*) malloc(aField->max_length);

memset (bind_result, 0, sizeof (bind_result));
bind_result[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB;
bind_result[0].is_null= 0;
bind_result[0].buffer= (char *) aBuffer;
bind_result[0].buffer_length= aField->max_length;
bind_result[0].length= &aMaxSize;

mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, bind_result);

std::string aStrData;
while(!mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt))
{
    fprintf(stdout, " size %d\n", (int) aMaxSize);
    aStrData = std::string(aBuffer,aMaxSize);
    fprintf(stdout, " data %s\n", aStrData.c_str());
}

free(aBuffer);

mysql_free_result(aRes);

if (mysql_stmt_close(stmt))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " failed while closing the statement\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I came upon this after a lot of trial and error as I have my code structured a bit different. I call mysql_stmt_bind_result() before mysql_stmt_store_result() as I was following examples from the MySQL manual. For example, page 2688 under mysql_stmt_fetch() has it that way but then the call to mysql_stmt_fetch() and STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH set returns nothing, no rows at all. So I had to modify the bindings for affected field with actual size, call mysql_stmt_bind_result() again and then it worked. Weird.